# Integrate laravel app with MS Active Directory but restrict users who can access

Tags: laravel, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I have a custom application for internal use only where currently users are created by a super admin. Some of the users are from within the business and some external e.g. suppliers/customers.

I'm looking for a way to integrate MS Active Directory as a login option but want to be able to restrict which users from the business can actually use this method.

I have search through all the MS docs and have all the documentation on the different oauth approaches but not sure which one would be suitable for my needs.

I am thinking that perhaps i need to give the admin a way to browse the AD and select the users that can login which then creates inactive user accounts in the mysql database with some sort of MS user ID. Then provide a 'Sign in with MS' button that does the usual auth redirection process to MS and back to the site. At that point I can check an ID and if that matches an allowed user account and if so, sync the rest of the data e.g. name, email, phone etc..

Links I've already found:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/tutorials/php

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-phpapp/tree/master/Demos/03-add-msgraph

Comment: Can you confirm if you're looking for signing users in with on-premises Active Directory, or with Azure Active Directory (the cloud service)?

Comment: Azure Active Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first order of business is enabling a user to sign in to the Laravel-based app. For this, I strongly recommend *not* trying to re-invent the wheel (at least not completely), and make use of an existing Laravel package. [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/socialite) is probably the best place to start, since it has a long list of existing [community-provided Socialite providers](https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/about.html), including three which work with Azure AD already: [Microsoft](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/tree/master/src/Microsoft), [Microsoft-Graph](https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/microsoft-graph.html) and [Microsoft-Azure](https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/microsoft-azure.html). (Note: Though I haven't tested any of these myself, the first two seem to be the most promising, as they use the newer v2 endpoint.)

When it comes to authorization (controlling access), you have two options:

1. *Control at Azure AD*

   Once you've got the app integrated with Azure AD, you can configure the app in Azure AD to require user assignment, and then control access to the app by assigning (or not) users to the app. Users who are not assigned won't even make it past the sign-in page.

   You can use Azure AD's existing experiences for [managing user and role assignment for the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups), or you could go all-out and build this experience directly into the Laravel-based app itself, making use of the Azure AD Graph API to create the [app role assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity and user picker experience.

   Hint: In either case, remember that you can make the app "superuser" an "owner" of the app in Azure AD (Azure AD > Enterprise apps > (app) > Owners), which will allow them to assign users without needing to give them any additional privileges in Azure AD.
2. *Control at the app*

   In this approach, you allow all users to sign in to the app with Azure AD, but then you use your app's own authorization logic to decide who makes it any further, and what roles they get in the app.

In reality, you will most likely find the best approach is to use a combination of the two, with some of the authorization enforced by Azure AD and the next level enforced by the app itself.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped clarify and I was able to get the sample code from the MS github repo working.

Answer (score 0):

If you would do it in this way, it will be necessary that the super-admin has always this permissions in the AAD. From my point of view it is less practical.

I would perfer such app-assigments with help of Service Principal. You assign a role (look for app roles) to the user and then your business logic must decide which permissions the user has. If you would use the app roles feature, then you can restrict access to the role with it's help. All the user can login, but only users with a specific role would be able to see a content of the app.

I hope this hints can help to find a right direction, but there is no silver bullet solution... :/